# SQL Query to get IDs of elements that have X number of counts in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if you could give me a hand with an SQL Query.
I have two tables: Designs and Votes.
The designs have votes from the users, so the structure of the Votes table looks something like this:

- vote_id
- user_id
- design_id

What I need, is to display in a web page all the designs that have less than 50 votes, but I'm struggling with the query... could you give me a hand?

I'm trying something like this, and it does return the Designs with less than 50 votes, however it does not include the designs with no votes at all.

```
    SELECT * FROM `votes` as Vote, `designs` as Design, `users` as User
WHERE `Design`.`id` = `Vote`.`design_id`
GROUP BY `Vote`.`design_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 50;
```

Needless to say I am a complete amateur in SQL..
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: You say ` less than 50 votes` but query says `COUNT(*) > 50`. Who is right?

Comment: Sorry, typo on the post with the less than sign... But I also need one with more than LOL...

Comment: Oh, @lorey got it right. I just wanted to ensure that his effort goes in right direction.

Comment: How do the tables relate to one another  - oh and please never use comma join syntax again!

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Nice work on spotting this one ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT designs.*, photo.* /* You only need designs */
FROM designs /* You are looking for designs, so start there */
JOIN photos ON designs.id = photos.design_id /* append the matching photo */
LEFT JOIN votes ON designs.id = votes.design_id /* append all votes */
GROUP BY designs.id /* group all rows by design */
HAVING COUNT(*) > 50;
```

What I am doing here: I select all designs and append the matching photo (`JOIN` because there is always one). Next I select all matching votes. You have to use `LEFT JOIN` to also select projects with no matching vote (`JOIN` would leave them out, try it without `GROUP BY` to grasp the difference). Then I `GROUP BY` design and can count by `HAVING`.

Note that this join because of the `GROUP BY` statement would get you a random user because there are several votes and therefore several users per design. So I left it out. Why do you need it? (Just leave me a comment on what you're trying to do)

For those wondering about `photos`, take a look at the comments:

> Each design has a photo and each vote comes from a user. So table
>   photos has a "desing_id" and Desing has "photo_id". Then vote has
>   "user_id" and Design has "vote_id"

To learn more about joins:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @lorey... I need the info related from tables "Users" and "Photos" (forgot to include it on the post) because I need to display some info on the page.
I tried your query but I get the error: #1054 - Unknown column 'design_id' in 'from clause' 
In the Designs table, the id column is just "ID", if I change it to that, I get zero results back =(

Comment: Okay, i take another look ;)

Comment: OK.. so this one:
SELECT `Design`.* /* You only need designs */
FROM `designs` as `Design` /* You are looking for designs, so start there */
LEFT JOIN `votes` AS `Vote` USING (id) /* append all votes */
GROUP BY `Design`.`id` /* group all rows by design */
HAVING COUNT(*) < 50;
Works.. but I also need a few related data from columns "users" and "photos"... how should I include those=?

Comment: Are you sure? if design_id is just id in the design table it won't do what you want. Does the latest query work? I just found another typo, sorry...

Comment: How are users and photos related to these results?

Comment: The current one works, it returns all the designs correctly, except for the extra data from other tables I need =(

Comment: Each design has a photo and each vote comes from a user. So table photos has a "desing_id" and Desing has "photo_id".
Then vote has "user_id" and Design has "vote_id"

Comment: The problem is that if you select one design per row you would get several votes of users. You should retrieve this information in another query. It would only be reasonable to select this if one design had one user. I'll add the photo table, but this is really easy ;)

Comment: Thanks a million @lorey! I'll try to do the thing with users in another query... it's really hard as I am using CakePHP and it's not as simple as just querying the database... or at least haven't found a way to do it (just started learning cakephp too)